# Magento 2 Random Order/Invoice/Shipping number

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, increment-id

I am looking into ways to implement random sequence for Order/Invoice/Shipping number and make sure they are unique in there entity type. Is there a way to make it correct? Since i know that it is generates/calculates in Magento_SalesSequence module here https://mage2.pro/t/topic/511

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via below code, Magento uses

`Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence::getNextValue()`

For next increment ID

So what you can can do is

Create a plugin and rewrite this method in your plugin

Your `di.xml` file located in `YourPackage/YourModule/etc` folder

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence">
        <plugin name="order_increment_id" type="YourPackage\YourModule\Plugin\Model\Sequence" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Your `Sequence.php` is,

```
<?php

namespace YourPackage\YourModule\Plugin\Model;

class Sequence
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function aroundGetNextValue(\Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        return $this->getIncrementIds();
    }
    // this methid ensure and check for random number in order table

    public function getIncrementIds()
    {
        $connection =  $this->connection->getConnection();
        $sql = "SELECT temp.rnd FROM sales_order c,(SELECT FLOOR((RAND()*99999999)) AS rnd FROM sales_order LIMIT 0,50) AS temp
                 WHERE c.increment_id NOT IN (temp.rnd) LIMIT 1";
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

        return $result[0]['rnd'];
    }
}
```